# how to store values from form and store it in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried :

```
<?php

$array = array();
for ($i=0;$i <20;$i++)
{
        $comm =  mysql_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
        array_push($array,$comm);
        echo $comm;

}

?>
```

but i am getting only 1 value.
i want to show all the values in the array

Comment: `$comm` has the same value in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: how to increment comm ? should write comm outside for loop ?

Comment: It is unclear from your question what you're trying to do. At the moment, you're assigning the result of `mysql_escape_string($_POST['comments'])` to `$comm`, 20 times. Please [edit] your question to make it clear what the different values should be.

Comment: FYI: You can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works and where everything is. (Welcome on SO!)

Answer (score 1):

Rizier123 answer is 100% correct, but just for your understanding you can use something like this too:

```
<?php
$array = array();
foreach ($_POST as $comm)
{
        $comm =  mysql_escape_string($comm);
        array_push($array,$comm);
        echo $comm;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you only go through this post variable: `$_POST['comments']`.

Make it simple and do something like this:

(Here I get all values with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) from the `$_POST` variable then I go through each element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and call `mysql_escape_string()` on them)

```
$array = array_map("mysql_escape_string", array_values($_POST));
```